# Export mysql data in CSV in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, csv

In CakePHP, with the following code i am trying to Export users email in CSV.
I am getting Errors.

[Code Refrence site](http://php-dev-zone.blogspot.in/2013/12/export-data-into-excel-or-csv-file-in.html)

**Error:**

```
Notice (8): Undefined offset: 0 [APP\View\Frontusers\admin_exportemails.ctp, line 12]

Warning (2): fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given [APP\View\Helper\CsvHelper.php, line 36]

Notice (8): Undefined offset: 1 [APP\View\Frontusers\admin_exportemails.ctp, line 12]

Warning (2): fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given [APP\View\Helper\CsvHelper.php, line 36]
```

**admin_exportemails.ctp**

```
$line= $useremails[0]['Frontuser'];
$this->CSV->addRow(array_keys($line));

foreach ($useremails as $key => $useremail)
{
      $line =$useremail[$key]['Frontuser'];
       $this->CSV->addRow($line);
}
$filename='useremails';
echo  $this->CSV->render($filename);
```

Comment: When posting errors it is advised to highlight the line in your code on which it is triggered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're messing up your foreach. You split it up in the `$key` and the `$useremail` sub-array, which is OK. But then you iterate over it and try to access `$useremail[$key]['Frontuser']` again, which is nonexistent at that point.

```
foreach ($useremails as $key => $useremail)
```

This causes the `[0]` and `[1]` in the original `$useremails` array to be set as `$key`, but you iterate over all the items over the `$useremails`, so you can simply:

```
$line = $useremail['Frontuser'];
```

You don't need the `$key`, since that's not part of the iterated item, e.g. the first time your foreach runs, it sees this:

```
[Frontuser] => Array
    (
        [name] => Rash
        [email] => rash.com
    )
```

And on the second iteration it sees this:

```
[Frontuser] => Array
    (
        [name] => John
        [email] => john@gmail.com
    )
```

So there is no `[0]` or `[1]` index anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
$useremail[$key]['Frontuser'];
```

should be

```
$useremail['Frontuser'];
```

Actually there's no need for your code to include the key in the foreach loop at all.

That's PHP 101, so for further information please refer to the manual: **http://php.net/foreach**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass your data array in that function and your csv generated in webroot folder. 
Note:- 1. You should put blank csv file at webroot folder.
       2. you should store all information in a sub array which contain only values not Model index.

```
function generate_csv($data_array=array()){
//        pr($data_array);die;

        foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) { 
            $newdata[] = $key.','.$value;
        }

//        pr($newdata);die;
    $f = fopen(APP.'webroot/csv_file.csv', 'w+');

    foreach ($newdata as $line) { 
        fputcsv($f, array($line), ','); 
    }

    fseek($f, 0);

    fclose($f);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you made mistake in the for loop and iterated it in wrong way.just ommit the below line from the foreach loop.

**$line =$useremail[$key]['Frontuser'];**

Answer (score 0):

Here have tow options 
1. save csv file in folder not sent output to browser and 
2. send output to browser

```
function generate_csv($data_array = array()) {

    //$f = fopen(APP . 'webroot/files/unsaved_bars.csv', 'w+'); // for save csv file in folder not sent output to browser 
    $f = fopen("php://output", "a"); // for send output to browser 

    $headers[] = array('id','name','other_info'); // for header row
    $data_array = array_merge($headers, $data_array);

    foreach ($data_array as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, ',');
    }
    //fseek($f, 0);
    fclose($f);
}
```